# Having clause usage in update statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update certain values using this query. I just want to update those rows using the dump for all the city names that appear once. Pls suggest a working approach.

```sql
UPDATE city_mst c,
          iata_cities ic
LEFT JOIN airport_dump ad
ON        ad.city = c.city_name
AND       ad.iata = c.iata_code
AND       ad.iata IS NOT NULL
JOIN      country_mst cm
ON        c.country_id = cm.country_id
AND       IF(cm.country_name = "United States of America","United States",IF(cm.country_name = "Russian Federation","Russia",cm.country_name)) = ad.country
SET       c.iata_code = ad.iata,
          ic.iata_code = ad.iata,
          c.airport_lat = ad.latitude,
          c.airport_long = ad.longitude,
          ic.airport_lat = ad.latitude ,
          ic.airport_long = ad.longitude
group BY  c.city_name
HAVING    count(c.city_name) < 2
```

I am getting the error of SQL syntax which I ll obviously get.

The select query for the same is :

-------------->> city iata = dump iata and single entry in city_mst

```sql
SELECT cm.country_name,
       Count(c.city_name),
       ad.country,
       c.city_id,
       ad.`airport id`,
       c.city_name  AS "CITY_MST | CITY_NAME",
       ad.city      AS "AIRPORT_DUMP | CITY_NAME",
       c.iata_code  AS "CITY_MST | IATA",
       ad.iata      AS "AIRPORT_DUMP | IATA",
       c.latitude   AS "CITY_MST | Latitude",
       ad.latitude  AS "AIRPORT_DUMP | Latitude",
       c.longitude  AS "CITY_MST | Longitude",
       ad.longitude AS "AIRPORT_DUMP | Longitude"
FROM   city_mst c
       LEFT JOIN airport_dump ad
              ON ad.city = c.city_name
                 AND ad.iata IS NOT NULL
                 AND ad.iata = c.iata_code
       JOIN country_mst cm
         ON c.country_id = cm.country_id
            AND IF(cm.country_name =
                    "united states of america", "united states", IF(
                    cm.country_name = "russian federation", "russia",
                country_name)) =
                ad.country
GROUP  BY c.city_name
HAVING Count(c.city_name) < 2
```

Comment: That looks a mess - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I guess he is trying to update if count is more than one. Before update have you tried select?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @James a well written question would not require guesswork

Comment: @P.Salmon Pls have a look now.

Comment: start your job by converting `comma-seperated` tables' list to `JOIN` seperated tables' list.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan okay ill give it a try.

Comment: A LEFT JOIN in an UPDATE statement is simply a really weird idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
UPDATE city_mst c LEFT JOIN
       (< your select query here>
       ) x
       ON c.city_id = x.city_id
    SET . . .;
```

Under these circumstances, your query should really be aggregating by `city_id` (not `city_name`) and select only the columns needed for the `SET` clause.

Also, an `INNER JOIN` is probably fine, but you haven't explained what you want to do.

Comment: I just want to update those rows using the dump for all the city names that appears once.

Comment: 'Probably'? I think we can say it's a dead certainty.